# openreadAsync vs Bitmap for image downloading from server

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have some image urls which I want to cache locally and save so that I don't need to make a web request again and again as needed.

Now, I am confused whether there is any significant benefit of using webclient's openreadasync method over bitmap for fetching the image for first time for saving it to IsolatedStorage.

For me, I think bitmap would be a better option as I would be able to get a event for progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post gives good info on various image caching options.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

Matt mentioned the fact that default image caching only works per session. So if you are implementing your own Image caching, then you will have to implement a image downloader for which the WebClient OpenReadAsync provides a way to store file locally

If you were't considering a local cache, UriSource would have been the choice.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen the question. Perhaps I hadn't framed my question properly, what I wanted to know was is their any benefit of using openReadAsync over bitmap urisource for fetching the image at start. I am maintaining a local imagecacher to avoid more than one request for fetching the same image.
Mainly I want to avoid too much work on UI thread.

Comment: If you want to save files locally before passing them to Image, you need to use HttpWebRequest or WebClient

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache images beyond the current application instance lifetime, have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/10/04/there-s-no-substitute-for-customer-feedback-improving-windows-phone-7-application-performance-now-a-bit-easier-with-lowprofileimageloader-and-deferredloadlistbox-updates.aspx which will show a way of saving the images to `IsolatedStorage` and then display it from there. This means you won't have to get it over the network each time the app is run.

If you're using this for lots of images be sure to manage the images you save as well so you don't fill up the disk with lots of old images you'll never need again.